# AFNetworking returns a _NSCFData object instead of JSON

Tags: afnetworking

I'm sending the following message to an instance of AFHTTPClient. I expect the success block to be sent a Foundation object (a dictionary) but the debugger shows me that JSON is a _NSCFData object.  [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159004/issue-with-retrieving-json-with-afnetworking) states that I need to set the Accept header to 'application/json'.  Well, I'm doing that but AFNetworking still is not decoding the JSON in the response body.  If I decode the json myself using NSJSONSerialization I get an NSDictionary as I expect.  What am I doing wrong?

```
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[client postPath:@"/app/open_connection/"
  parameters:params
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
         NSLog(@"successful login! %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"status"]);
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error opening connection");
         NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
         [alert runModal];
     }
];
```

Note: I'm programming the server in Python using Django.  The content type of the response is 'application/json'

Comment: Try adding [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ... I think there maybe something wrong with your client settings.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/app/open_connection/" parameters:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"successful login! %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"status"]);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"error opening connection");
        NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
        [alert runModal];
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: That works, so it must be a problem with the configuration of my AFHTTPClient.

Comment: For me, the problem was that the content was being returned as text/html. At first, I thought I could simply modify the acceptableContentTypes to add text/html, but that still resulted in NSCF data because apparently it needs to be in the appropriate mime type to enable the content to be parsed properly as JSON instead of one big blob of text.

Answer (score 6):

When you're working with `AFHTTPClient` and a JSON API, you will typically need to set all three of these settings:

```
httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

Now when you make requests using your client, it will know to parse the response as JSON.

```
[httpClient postPath:@"/app/open_connection/"
          parameters:params
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                 NSLog(@"JSON! %@", response);
             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             }];
```

Here's a trick that I discovered as well. In the `NSError` object you can parse it and retrieve the error message (if the HTTP response had a JSON error message):

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *JSON =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [error.localizedRecoverySuggestion dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:nil];
           failureCallback(JSON[@"message"]);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't figure out why AFHTTPClient was returning NSCFData - turns out "application/json" was not set. Thank you so much!