# AFNetworking AFHTTPClient AFJSONRequestOperation not using JSON Operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I followed this Screencast... http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/6-afnetworking

My singleton `AFHTTPClient` code is...

```
+ (MyClient *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static MyClient *myClient;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { myClient = [[MyClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyBaseURL]];});
    return myClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        // these are not actual values but I am setting default headers.
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"sdfg" value:@"4"];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"std" value:@"3"];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"reg" value:@"5"];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"yu" value:@"1"];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"xv" value:@"3"];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"hmm" value:@"5"];

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I'm executing it like...

```
[[MyClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"blah.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSMutableArray *stats = [NSMutableArray array];

        // it crashes on the next line because responseObject is NSData
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject) {
            CCStatistic *stat = [[CCStatistic alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];

            [stats addObject:stat];
        }

        self.stats = stats;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error retrieving!");
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

It all works fine. I've intercepted it with Charles and it is sending the correct request and receiving the correct JSON except the operation is not a JSON operation.

So the `responseObject` is `NSData` not the `JSON object` that I was expecting.

An I missing any config to use the JSON operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of code that in your case is deciding whether the request is processable by a JSON operation is the following:

```
return [[self acceptableContentTypes] intersectsSet:AFContentTypesFromHTTPHeader([request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"])];
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163845/846273) by Mattt Thompson (the author of `AFNetworking`) you have to set the `Accept` header for the request to `application/json`.

This is not intuitive and it's highly implementation-dependent, but it works.

Add

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

to your client initialization and it should be ok, regardless of the path extension.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there is a check in the AFNetworking code that throes out the JSON operation if the request url extension is not `json`.

Because mine is `php` it's throwing it out.

Changing the code worked.

**My Change**

In the `AFJSONRequestOperation` method...

```
+ (BOOL)canProcessRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return [[[request URL] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"json"] || [super canProcessRequest:request];
}
```

I changed it to...

```
+ (BOOL)canProcessRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    // added php to the request valid path extensions.
    return [[[request URL] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"json"] || [super canProcessRequest:request] || [[[request URL] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"php"];
}
```

It's not really a bug per se more like a random syntax style of the requests that are open to me.

Is it normal to have `.php` requests returning JSON?

Comment: What did you change? The `AFNetworking` code? Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159004/issue-with-retrieving-json-with-afnetworking) be related?

Comment: in any case you should fill in an issue on github ;)

Comment: have you checked the `super` implementation?

Comment: Hmm... it checks the "ContentType" header values.