# AFNetworking's requestWithMethod:path:parameters: Returning NSMutableURLRequest That Doesn't Persist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking version 0.10.x for iOS 4.3 compatibility. This version of AFNetworking does not use arc so AFHTTPClient as well as the other AFNetworking classes have the `fno-objc-arc` flag applied to each of them (the rest of my project is using ARC). In a function I have the following code:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:method
                                                           path:nil
                                                     parameters:adjustedParameters];
NSLog(@"returning: %@", urlRequest);
return urlRequest;
```

The problem I am seeing is that urlRequest is always returned as NULL.

I have even stepped through this code with a debugger:

[image: picture depicting issue]

As you can see, the log is printing out a value of null while the debugger is stating that url request points to a valid memory address. I am running my project on iOS 6.0 with Xcode 4.6.3. Any idea as to what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the method `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` was returning a nil request object because I was passing `nil` as the path parameter. My code should have read:

```
urlRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:method
                                      path:@""
                                parameters:adjustedParameters];
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the default header's accept return type.
 for example in my code I have:
`[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html"]` it could also be `application/json` depending on your return type header.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9163845/766570) for more details (although the response the OP is getting in the mentioned link is different than yours.. it may be due the difference between ARC and non-ARC)

Comment: I tried `[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];` to no avail. Besides the issue is that the object isn't being allocated/persisted properly, not an AFNetworking configuration problem.