# Is there a way to register custom accept headers to parse as JSON in AFNetworking 1.3?

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I have a server that is sending back JSON using the following accept header:

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/vnd.com.test.v1+json"];
```

In the success block of the API calls, the response data is coming back as a `NSData` object.

I read in the following question [Issue with retrieving JSON with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159004/issue-with-retrieving-json-with-afnetworking) that I need to set `@"application/json"` if I want JSON to be parsed into an `NSDictionary` automatically, otherwise I have to manually do it for each call using `NSJSONSerialization`.

Is there a way that I can get `@"application/vnd.com.test.v1+json"` to be recognized as JSON and automatically do JSON deserialization for each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your desired content types to [`AFHTTPRequestOperation`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html) using [`addAcceptableContentTypes:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/addAcceptableContentTypes%3a):

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/vnd.com.test.v1+json"];
```